# How to print each line of a file as many times as according to the number in the first column

Tags: text-processing, awk, string

```
Input_file:
1 string1 
4 string2
2 string3
...

Output_file:
1 string1
4 string2
4 string2
4 string2
4 string2
2 string3
2 string3
...
```

Here's my code and it didn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
N=0
cat input_file | while read LINE; do

    N=$((N+1))

awk '{for(i=0;i<'$1';i++);print}' $LINE >> output_file

done
```

Comment: No shell loop is necessary: `awk '{for(i=0;i<$1;i++) print}' Input_file`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354457/how-to-print-each-line-of-a-file-as-many-times-as-according-to-the-number-in-the#comment627998_354457):

```
awk '{for(i=0;i<$1;i++) print}' input_file > output_file
```

This loops over each line of `input_file`; on each line, it loops `i` according to the first field and prints the current line that many times. The whole output is then redirected to `output_file`.

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`

```
$ cat ip.txt 
1 string1 
4 string2
2 string3
$ perl -ane 'print $_ x $F[0]' ip.txt 
1 string1 
4 string2
4 string2
4 string2
4 string2
2 string3
2 string3
```

- `-a` option to split input line on spaces and save to `@F` array
- `-n` loop over input file, by default newline is line separator. Don't print input lines
- `-e` execute Perl code
- `print $_ x $F[0]` explicit print to repeat input line `$_` number of times specified by first field `$F[0]`

Comment: `perl -ne 'print $_ x $_'` would also work (or `perl -pe '$_ x= $_'`).

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pae '$_ = $_ x $F[0]' input_file

perl -nae 'print while $F[0]--' inputfile

perl -pae 's/^.*\n\K/$`/m while --$F[0]' inputfile

while IFS= read -r l; do yes "$l" | head -n "${l%%[!0-9]*}"; done < inputfile

while IFS= read -r l; do csh -c "repeat ${l%%[!0-9]*} echo '$l'"; done < inputfile

while IFS= read -r l; do
   for k in $(seq "${l%%[!0-9]*}"); do echo "$l"; done
done < inputfile
```