# Expand a range of a file based on columns

Tags: awk

I have a file with a start and end number, like below

```
Start,end,code
43786,67883,avb
200,400,add
12,14,adf
```

I need to however rewrite this so that all the numbers in the range between start and end are written with their code:

```
43786,Avb
43787,avb
43788,avb
43789,avb
```

Till the last 67883,avb in that range and continue to

```
200,add
201,add
202,add
```

Comment: Not much different from [How to print each line of a file as many times as according to the number in the first column](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354457/how-to-print-each-line-of-a-file-as-many-times-as-according-to-the-number-in-the)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should be enough:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for(i=$1;i<=$2;i++) print i,$3}' input_file > output_file
```

If your file has a header that you need not to print, then:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR>1{for(i=$1;i<=$2;i++) print i,$3}' input_file > output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F, -lane '$. > 1 and print "$_,$F[2]" for $F[0] .. $F[1]'

perl -F, -lane '$. == 1 && next, print "$a,$F[2]" while ($a=$F[0]++) <= $F[1]'

while IFS=, read -r start end str junk; do
   case ${v++} in '' ) v=; continue ;; esac
   seq -f "%g,$str" $start $end
done

while IFS=, read -r start end str junk; do
   case ${v++} in '' ) v=; continue ;; esac
   yes "$str" | sed -e "$start,$end!d;=;${end}q" | sed -e 'N;s/\n/,/'
done
```